# missing right parenthesis error in create table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am getting the above error when making these create table statements:  Any advice?

```
create table USER_PROFILE 
(
     email varchar(24), 
     name varchar(24), 
     birthday char(11), 
     major varchar(24), 
     username varchar(24), 
     PRIMARY KEY (email)
);

create table COURSE 
(
     courseID number, 
     cName varchar(24), 
     instructor varcahr(24), 
     PRIMARY KEY(courseID)
);

create table USER_COURSE 
(
     email varchar(24), 
     courseID number, 
     PRIMARY KEY(email, courseID), 
     FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (email), 
     FOREIGN KEY (courseID) REFERENCES COURSE (courseID)
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Don't just put it in the title...

Comment: Your queries are correct except the typing error in second query, but if still getting error then try giving primary key and foreign key at column level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error in your second table creation. `varcahr` instead of `varchar`

```
create table USER_PROFILE (email varchar(24), name varchar(24), birthday 
char(11), major varchar(24), username varchar(24), PRIMARY KEY (email));

create table COURSE (courseID number, cName varchar(24), instructor 
varchar(24), PRIMARY KEY(courseID));

create table USER_COURSE (email varchar(24), courseID number, PRIMARY 
KEY(email, courseID), FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES USER_PROFILE (email), 
FOREIGN KEY (courseID) REFERENCES COURSE (courseID));
```